# how to use GCM in openshift node server

Tags: android, node.js, web-services, openshift, google-cloud-messaging

I am very new to OPENSHIFT, GCM and NODE.js. I want to use GCM service in my node server which is hosted  on openshift. I want create api key to use GCM. To crate new key google ask ip address of my server. but I think openshift has not provide static IP for cartridges(node, php, java, etc..). so how can I get static ip to create key? or is there  way to create api key without giving static IP?. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

There´s a ready to use cartridge called aerogear http://aerogear.org/

If you search for that in openshift, you can install and use it out of the box.

It kind-of isolates you from GCM or whatever the push system behind that. I´m still missing some features thoug...